# Agregar un elemento a un Lista enlazada (linkedlist) y corroborar

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo hacer una función que agregue un valor en una posición indicada, y adicional diga true si fue agregada correctamente.

En Conclusión si me llegan a pasar la posición y el valor y llega a estar arrojar true. Bueno aparte de AGREGARLO.

Aquí esta el ejercicio y el código que llevo, no se si alguien puede darme una mano para ver en que estoy fallando.

EJERCICIO
Implementar el método **addInPos** dentro del **prototype** de **LinkedList** que deberá agregar un elemento en la posición indicada.

Ambos datos serán brindados como parámetro (pos, value). Donde "**pos**" será la
posición en la cual se deberá agregar el valor "**value**".

En el caso de que la posición en la que se quiera hacer la inserción no sea válida (Supere el tamaño de la lista actual) debe devolver false.

Si el nodo fue agregado correctamente devolver true.
Aclaración: la posición cero corresponde al head de la LinkedList

```
// Implementar el método addInPos dentro del prototype de LinkedList que deberá agregar un elemento en
// la posición indicada. Ambos datos serán brindados como parámetro (pos, value). Donde "pos" será la
// posición en la cual se deberá agregar el valor "value". En el caso de que la posición en la que se
// quiera hacer la inserción no sea válida (Supere el tamaño de la lista actual) debe devolver false.
// Si el nodo fue agregado correctamente devolver true.
// Aclaración: la posición cero corresponde al head de la LinkedList
// Ejemplo 1:
//    Suponiendo que la lista actual es: Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [4]
//    lista.addInPos(2, 3);
//    Ahora la lista quedaría: Head --> [1] --> [2] --> [3] --> [4]
// Ejemplo 2:
//    Suponiendo que la lista está vacía: Head --> null
//    lista.addInPos(2, 3); --> Debería devolver false ya que no es posible agregar en la posición 2
//    sin antes tener cargada la posición 0 y 1.


    LinkedList.prototype.addInPos = function(pos, value){
    
      let nodo = this.head 
      let previo;                             
      let counter = 0;                        
      let nuevoNodo = new Node(value);
    
      // detectamos el tamaño e hicimos de la lista
    
       
      while ( node) {
        counter++;
        node = node.next;
    }
    
       //Determinar que el indice no sea nulo y retorne false
    
       if( pos < 0 || pos > counter) {return false};
    
      // Agregamos el nuevo nodo con indice en la lista.
    
       if (pos === 0) {
           nuevoNodo.next = nodo;
           this.head = nuevoNodo
       } else {
    
          for (var i = 0; i < pos ; i++) {
            previo = nodo;
            nodo = nodo.next;
          }
           
           nuevoNodo.next = nodo;
           previo.next =nuevoNodo;
    
         // Aqui comprovamos el método.
    
           if (nuevoNodo.value === value ) {
            return true;
           }
       }
    
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El código se puede simplificar mucho. Por ejemplo, no necesitás contar los nodos de la lista ya que de todas formas la tenés que recorrer para encontrar la posición de inserción. Así que es más fácil buscar esa posición y simplemente fallar si se llega al final sin encontrarla.

```
LinkedList.prototype.addInPos = function(pos, value){

    let cursor = this.head;
    let anterior = null;
    let posicionCursor = 0;     
    let nuevoNodo = new Node(value);

    if (pos < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    while (posicionCursor < pos && cursor != null) {
        posicionCursor++;
        anterior = cursor;
        cursor = cursor.next;
    }

    if (posicionCursor < pos) {
        return false;
    }

    nuevoNodo.next = cursor;
    if (anterior != null) {
        anterior.next = nuevoNodo;
    }
}
```

1. salimos si pos es menor a cero.
2. Avanzamos siempre que exista el siguiente nodo y que no hayamos llegado a la posición de inserción.
3. Si salimos del bucle pero el cursor está posicionado antes de la posición que nos pidieron, nos piden insertar por fuera de la lista. Retornamos false.
4. Finalmente apuntamos desde el nuevo nodo al nodo actual (que podría ser null) y si tenemos un nodo anterior (es decir que no nos pidieron insertar al principio) le decimos que el siguiente elemento es el nuevo.

Tené en cuenta que no pude probar el código y JS no es el lenguaje que mejor manejo. Pero la idea del algoritmo que te presento te va a servir.